# How to enable Facebook Like in GameCenter for iOS 8?

Tags: ios, game-center

I have update leaderboard and achievements in GameCenter using Objective-C code. But the issue is whenever I open GameCenterController using code it shows Facebook Like unavailable.
How can I fix it? I had also logged into Facebook in the Phone Settings. 
What I have to do?

Comment: i am jst setting score and achievement and nothing more ,just need to know know to enable facebook liking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to enable Facebook like in GameCenter, you need to create an App on Facebook and release it with same bundle identifier. This will enable the Facebook liking button, and maps the link to your App published on both App store as well as Facebook page.

> Note: This will work only for App store environment (i.e., it won't work on Sandbox environment.)

Register your app [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register).
Hope it helps.

Comment: do i have to integrate Facebook SDK and code for its integration in Project for likeButton ?

Comment: No, you don't need to integrate Facebook SDK for that. You just need to publish your App from Facebook.